# font-size specified on body element is ignored by input

Tags: css, input, font-size

I have a basic web page here http://www.webdevout.net/test?0V, reproduced below

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
 <style type="text/css">
 body { font-size: 12px;}
 </style>
 <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
 <p>test</p>
 <form action="/foo" method="get">
  <fieldset>
   <input type="text" value="bar" />
  </fieldset>
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

When i use firebug to inspect the page, the text "test" is 12px as expected, but the text "bar" in the input is 11px, i would expect it to be 12px. Whats going on please?

Comment: Some additional information http://www.komodomedia.com/blog/2006/10/css-trickery-part-5-inheritance/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the browser you are using the default value for the `font-size` property is not `inhert` or a percentage, em or other relative length value. i.e. it is an absolute value.

Set the font-size property yourself, e.g. `input { font-size: 100%; }`

Consider using a [reset stylesheet](http://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&source=hp&q=reset%20stylesheet&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=).

Comment: Thanks for the reply David, but doesn't CSS inheritance state that the input will adopt the style of its parent, which will in-turn inherit off its parent, eventually reaching the <body> element, where the font-size is specified as 12px. Interestingly, this problem came about from using Eric Meyers reset stylesheet.

Comment: @pingu — only if the value of the font-size property is set to `inherit`, which it isn't.

Comment: @David — Support for `font-size: 100%` is rather better than support for `font-size: inherit`.

Comment: @David - in that case, wouldn't input { font-size: 100%; } be a good candidate for the reset stylesheet? how come none of them include that?

Comment: @pingu — you'd have to ask their authors.

Answer (score 2):

Some browsers style form elements based on their corresponding OS user interface elements. Therefore they might not honor all the styles you apply on `body` (i.e. they might not inherit from it).

You need to select these specific elements then apply the rules.

```
body, input {
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks BoltClock, i have not seen any mention of this in the rules governing specificity, is it just inputs? or selects as well?

Comment: Inputs, selects, buttons and textareas I think.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
* {
    font-size:12px;
}
```

Comment: That fixes it, but its a bit of a sledge hammer, i shouldn't have to do that should i?

Comment: Well since all visible elements go into body, it's really not any different except that it works on inputs also.